# Python create different thread calling the same function

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

in my project i have a class of threading.Thread like this:

```
class MakeHtml(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, *rstext):
        self.outhtml = [x for x in rstext]
        self.retval = ''
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        ...do something
```

in another file i call, every 10 seconds MakeHtml class

```
t = MakeHtml(mrr1, mrr2, mrr3, mrr4)
```

for create a thread but in this way i see that the thread is the same every time.

I need a new thread every time i call the MakeHtml Threading class, how can i do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

MakeHtml extends Thread, but if you have only 1 instance of MakeHtml, you will have only one thread

For instance if you want 2 different thread you will have to do

```
t = MakeHtml(mrr1, mrr2, mrr3, mrr4) # one thread
t1 = MakeHtml(mrr1, mrr2, mrr3, mrr4) # another one
```

You can use :

```
import threading

def afunction(mm):
   # do job
   pass

threads = []
for mm in [mmr1, mmr2, mmr3n mmr4]:
    t = threading.Thread(target=afunction, args=[mm,])
    threads.append(t)
    t.start()
[t.join() for t in threads]
```